# Realm Swift updating objects not working

Tags: realm, updatemodel, realm-cocoa

I'm using realm swift v1.0.0 and I create an object and I want to update its value permanently. 
Following the official guide and some other answers on stackoverflow I've done:

```
let myobject = MyObjectClass()
myobject.property1 = "test"
try! myrealm.write {
    myrealm.add(myobject)
}
```

And myrealm is a global variable:

```
let myrealm = try! Realm()
```

When I recover all the values of MyObjectClass I get back myobject with some initial values set in the init of the class (so the values that I set as initial values are stored properly), but property1 is (null) (as it is declared as an optional string).

But if I look at myobject in the function where I write the code above, its property1 is set to "test", but it's not saved permanently in the Realm db.

Can anyone help me to find out why it doesn't update the value of property1?
I've also tried to do:

```
try! myrealm.write {
    myrealm.add(myobject, update: true)
}
```

**EDIT:**

This is my model:

```
public class MyObjectClass(): Object {
   //[...]
   public dynamic var property1: String? = nil
   public dynamic var property2: MyObjectClass2?
}
```

Same problem happens with property2 which is another Realm Object.

Comment: Could you show me your model definitions? I suspect the properties wasn't declare as `dynamic`.

Comment: I have edited the post with the model definition

Comment: How did you make sure the property1 is nil? If you use debugger to see the value, appearing nil is intended behavior. Please use `print()` method in your code or use `po` in the LLDB console. It's intended behavior. Realm does not copy any data until actually access the properties. When access the properties, Realm fetch the data directly from its file. So Realm does not store any data to its ivar. That's why you cannot see any values via the debugger and nil out all value after committed.

Comment: I use print:
try! myrealm.write {
    myrealm.add(myobject, update: true)
}
print("\(myrealm.objects(MyObjectClass))") 

and it prints the object with the init values set in the init function of the class, but the value of the property that I have set are (null). I tried also to set the string property with a value:
public dynamic var property1 = "value1" 
and then to change the value, but it doesn't update it.

Comment: It seems your code should work for me. Can you share a reproducible project?

Comment: Ok I fixed it. The problem was the class MyObjectClass. I still have to figure out why (I didn't have time yet), but the problem was with overriding the init functions and doing operations there. I have rewritten the class and it works. Strange but was my fault :)

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue now. Could you explain how you solved it? @Andrea.Ferrando